# Is $1_{A_{\omega 1}}$ equal to $(1_A)_{\omega 1}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Is $1_{A_{\omega 1}}$ equal to $(1_A)_{\omega 1}$?

Here $1_x$ is the indicator function and $A_{\omega 1}$ is defined as $\{\omega _2:(\omega _1,\omega _2)\in A\}$

I don't know what approach to take here. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(\mathbf{1}_A)_x$ is shorthand for $y\mapsto \mathbf{1}_A(x,y)$, then
$$
\mathbf{1}_{A_{x}}(y)=1\iff y\in A_x\iff (x,y)\in A\iff \mathbf{1}_A(x,y)=1\iff (\mathbf{1}_A)_x(y)=1.
$$